# ADO.Net Data Acess Layer - should int results of ExecuteNonQuery be passed up to domain layer?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Should `int` results of `ExecuteNonQuery` bubble up to upper layers? For example, should the `interface` in my domain project return an `int` for updating or deleting entities as well?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Update a task
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="task">Task object to be updated</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int Update(Task task)
    {
        string query = "update tasks set userIdAssignedTo = @userIdAssignedTo, name = @name, status = @status where id = @id";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", task.Id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("userIdAssignedTo", ((object)task.UserIdAssignedTo) ?? DBNull.Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", task.Name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("status", ((object)task.Status) ?? DBNull.Value);
        return ExecuteNonQuery(command);
    }
```

Comment: Since you're updating one task, it would make more sense to return a `bool` than an `int` -  but do you think the domain model knows what to do when it returns `false` or `0`? Or would that be an `Exception`al scenario that you cannot handle?

Comment: Well this depends on your app, only you can say if it should or not. This is primarily opinion based I'm afraid.

Comment: The return value can be interesting for upper layers for debugging purposes ... if it is 0 the Task with the given Id was not found in the database